# Generating coordinate of a point that belongs to a line

Tags: math

Assume that a line is drawn using the points A which has the coordinate(X0,Y0) and B which has the coordinate(X1,Y1), Is there a random algorithm I can use to generate coordinates of random points between A and B that rests on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the slope of the line using:

```
m = (Y1 - Y0)/(X1 - X0)
```

Then you can compute any point on the line using:

```
y = m*(x - X0) + Y0
```

To actually compute the value for y point between there using any loop/iteration by using something like:

```cpp
for (int x = X0 + 1; x < X1; x++) {
    int new_point = m*(x - X0) + Y0;
}
```

Of course, you can set your own step sizes and use double or whatever is needed.

If you want the points to be random instead of selected uniformly you can use a random generator to generate values in the domain `(X0, X1)` (the implementation for this would be language specific) and plug them into the formula again to get the y-coordinate for the random x-coordinate.